# Why is UIButton.titleLabel?.text always switching back after I changed it in Swift 5 (UIKit)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uikit

I ran into an issue with my UIButton.

> After the User presses the button, it activates an **IBAction** which is supposed to change the `titleLabel.text` of my **UIButton**.

```swift
self.btnAppleHealthKit.titleLabel?.text = "Already pressed."
```

> *Whenever I press the button*, the **text changes** for about a quarter second to `"Already pressed"`, **but switches back immediately to the previous text.**

**Important Note:** The whole thing is inside a completion handler but I wrapped it into `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`

Can you guys think of an idea why this error appears?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, `UIButton` does not allow to configure `text` or `color` of `titleLabel`.

From [apple doc.s](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623992-titlelabel)

> Do not use the label object to set the text color or the shadow color.
>   Instead, use the setTitleColor(*:for:) and setTitleShadowColor(*:for:)
>   methods of this class to make those changes. **To set the actual text of
>   the label, use setTitle(_:for:) (button.titleLabel.text does not let
>   you set the text)**.

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved the problem. Didn't know that.